# Retrieving data from database from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to retrieve related data from the relationships table, after user clicks on the the bookname on the previous page. Nothing is being printed on the page even though in the database there is data.

The table schema is:

relationshipID,bookone,booktwo,relation,relationlike,relationdislike

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Retrieve Relationships</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <dl>

    <?php
    // Connect to database server
    mysql_connect("latcs7.cs.latrobe.edu.au","12ice06","EsnYkuxuwh9RbtQuRcQt") or die (mysql_error ());

    // Select database
    mysql_select_db("12ice06") or die(mysql_error());
        $sTitle=0;
    // Get data from the database depending on the value of the id in the URL
    $title = (isset($_GET['title']) && is_string($_GET['title'])) ? $_GET['title'] : null;
$sTitle = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
$strSQL = "SELECT R.bookone, B.title, B.author,
        R.booktwo, B.title, B.author,
        R.relation, R.relationlike, R.relationdislike 
        FROM relationships R
        INNER JOIN books B ON R.bookone = B.bookid";     

$rs = mysql_query($strSQL) or die(mysql_error());
    // Loop the recordset $rs

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
    // Write the data of the book


    echo "<dt>Book One:</dt><dd>" . $row["bookone"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Title:</dt><dd>" . $row["title"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Author:</dt><dd>" . $row["author"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Book Two:</dt><dd>" . $row["booktwo"] . "</dd>";
        echo "<dt>Title:</dt><dd>" . $row["title"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Author:</dt><dd>" . $row["author"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Relationship:</dt><dd>" . $row["relation"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Likes:</dt><dd>" . $row["relationshiplikes"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Dislikes:</dt><dd>" . $row["relationshipdislikes"] . "</dd>";
}

echo $strSQL;
    // Close the database connection
    mysql_close();
    ?>

    </dl>
    <p><a href="search_bookl.php">Return to the list</a></p>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: unfortunately its the language we were told to use for this assignment.

Comment: Have you tried this query directly in mysql? does it return any rows?

Comment: echo this query and run in database?

Comment: Is there something like `if(condition){code}while(condition);` for loops in PHP?

Comment: what are you doing selecting from two tables like this is a bad practice instead use joins also echo your result at every step and use mysql_error or die to find out the problem

Comment: if(){}while(); doesn't look like valid code to me, or at least I wouldn't expect it to do what I think you want it to.

Comment: Try also change expression at condition:

    WHERE relationships.bookone = books.bookid
      AND books.title='{$sTitle}'

Or in books.bookid your have title of book?

Comment: it likes everything but the very last piece of code

Comment: bookid does not contain the name, bookeone reference is for the database user only.

what im trying to do is get the booknames(title) and authors come up when a person clicks on a relationship. 

title isnt in the relationships table, its in the book table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){

    // Write the data of the book
    echo "<dt>Book One:</dt><dd>" . $row["bookone"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Book Two:</dt><dd>" . $row["booktwo"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Relationship:</dt><dd>" . $row["relation"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Likes:</dt><dd>" . $row["relationshiplikes"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Dislikes:</dt><dd>" . $row["relationshipdislikes"] . "</dd>";
}while($row!=0);
```

Should be

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
    // Write the data of the book
    echo "<dt>Book One:</dt><dd>" . $row["bookone"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Book Two:</dt><dd>" . $row["booktwo"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Relationship:</dt><dd>" . $row["relation"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Likes:</dt><dd>" . $row["relationshiplikes"] . "</dd>";
    echo "<dt>Dislikes:</dt><dd>" . $row["relationshipdislikes"] . "</dd>";
}
```

Comment: Check your sql, do you really mean `books.bookid=relationships.bookone 
                  AND relationships.bookone='{$sTitle}'` ? `books.book_id` and `$sTitle` ? they same?

Comment: no, bookone is a foreign key of the books table, it references title in the book table.

I'm trying to get the book title and author to print with the relationship it has with other books.

Comment: my problem is now that its only taking 1 title/author per relationship where I need it to print out bookOnes title and author, then booktwos title and author

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My advice:

a) Please reform the variable in your SQL-Statement like this:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT [...]
           WHERE books.bookid=relationships.bookone 
               AND relationships.bookone='".$sTitle."'";
```

b) Make sure your variable `$sTitle` isn't empty. If it still is an issue, echo the whole SQL-Statement (`echo $strSQL;`) for further debugging.

c) While on it, please reform the whole SQL statement. The following statement does the same and is much more readable:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT R.bookone, R.booktwo, 
              R.relation,
              R.relationlike, R.relationdislike
           FROM relationships R
           INNER JOIN books B ON R.bookone = B.bookid
           WHERE R.bookone='".$sTitle."'";
```

d) Instead of outputting the data after `if($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){`, use a while-statement instead, something like

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    // Write the data of the book
    // Insert your echos here
}
```

e) Question:
Is there a specific reason table books is `INNER JOIN`ed, but not used in a condition?

Comment: this is what the debugger printed out

SELECT R.bookone, R.booktwo, R.relation, R.relationlike, R.relationdislike FROM relationships R INNER JOIN books B ON R.bookone = B.bookid WHERE R.bookone=''

Comment: Then your variable `$sTitle` is empty. Make sure `$_GET['title']` is really set and available.